# Prove that $\sum_{i,j=1}^Nx_i\alpha_{ij}x_j>0$ for a non-symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A=(\alpha)_{i,j=1}^N$ a real square matrix. The matrix $A$ is not necessary symmetric. I want to prove that
$$\sum_{i,j=1}^Nx_i\alpha_{ij}x_j>0,\;\;\;\forall (x_1,\ldots,x_N)\in\mathbb{R}^N\backslash\left\lbrace 0\right\rbrace.$$

If matrix $A$ was symmetric, one way to do this, is to prove that all eigenvalues are positive. How can I deal with this case?

Comment: Replace $\alpha$ with $\frac{1}{2}(\alpha + \alpha^t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any real square matrix $A$ can be written (uniquely) as the sum of a symmetric matrix and a skew-symmetric matrix

$$A = A_{\text{sym}} + A_{\text{sq}}$$

where 
$$A_{\text{sym}} = \frac{1}{2} ( A + A^t) \\
A_{\text{sq}} = \frac{1}{2} ( A - A^t) $$

Say $A_{\text{sym}}= (\tilde \alpha_{ij})$. It is easy to see that 
$$\sum_{i,j=1}^Nx_i\alpha_{ij}x_j=\sum_{i,j=1}^Nx_i\tilde\alpha_{ij}x_j $$ ( that is, $A$ and $A_{\text{sym}}$ produce the same quadratic form). Now you are reduced to checking whether the real symmetric matrix $A_{\text{sym}}$ is positive definite, which is standard.

Answer (score 0):

This is false.  Consider $A=-I_N$ and $x_1=x_2=\cdots=x_N=1$.  Then
$$\sum_{i,j=1}^Nx_ia_{i,j}x_j=-N.$$

Comment: It isn't clear, but I think the OP has a particular $\alpha$ in mind or is asking about techniques for proving this sort of result in general. (Of course, symmetric does not imply positive-semidefinite.)